# How Do I Make Python Tkinter Widgets Created in a Loop Independant?

Tags: python, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

I've tried putting the widgets into lists via appending with no luck. I created everything in a for-loop, but I want each month's listbox to have it's own scrollbar. Currently only the last listbox works correctly and moving other months scrollbars moves the listbox for December.

Eventually each day with be clickable and open another window for adding daily transactions.

[image]

```
    mainFrame = tk.Frame(tkRoot)
    mainFrame.config(bd=2, relief='groove')
    mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=60)

    trxLabel = tk.Label(mainFrame, text='Transactions ' + str(year), font='courierNew 20 bold')
    trxLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=12, pady=(20, 0))

    # Hold each month frame
    self.monthFrame = []
    self.dayList = []
    self.endBalList = []
    self.vScroll = []

    for i in range(12):
        monthLabel = tk.Label(mainFrame, text=month[i][0], font='courierNew 12 bold')
        monthLabel.grid(row=1, column=i, pady=(20, 0))

        self.monthFrame.append(tk.Frame(mainFrame))
        self.monthFrame[i].config(bd=2, relief='groove')
        self.monthFrame[i].grid(row=2, column=i, sticky=tk.W)

        self.dayList.append(tk.Listbox(self.monthFrame[i], width=3))
        self.dayList[i].config(bd=2, relief='sunken')
        self.dayList[i].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.endBalList.append(tk.Listbox(self.monthFrame[i], width=16))
        self.endBalList[i].config(bd=2, relief='raised', background='LIGHT GRAY')
        self.endBalList[i].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        self.vScroll.append(tk.Scrollbar(self.monthFrame[i], orient='vertical'))
        self.vScroll[i].grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E))

        # Insert data
        for j in range(month[i][1]):
            self.dayList[i].insert(tk.END, 1 + j)
            self.endBalList[i].insert(tk.END, '999,999,999.99')

            self.getFrame(idx=i)

def getFrame(self, idx):
    self.dayList[idx].config(yscrollcommand=self.vScroll[idx].set)
    self.endBalList[idx].config(yscrollcommand=self.vScroll[idx].set)
    self.scrollAll(idx)

def scrollAll(self, idx):
    self.dayList[idx].yview(idx)
    self.endBalList[idx].yview(idx)
```

Comment: There are dozens of questions on stackoverflow about creating widgets in loops. Have you read through any of them to understand the underlying principles?

Comment: I have read quite a few of those questions, but I'm confused as to what I'm supposed to do once the widget is stored in the list. I figured it would work something like dayLabelID[i].config, dayLabelID[i].grid for example.

Comment: Ask  yourself this: if `scrollBoth` calls `self.daysList.yview`, how do you think it's supposed to know which iteration of the loop it should be concerned with? `self.daysList` can only reference a single widget at any one time.

Comment: I get that and added indexes to those but no dice. I tried adding command=functools.partial(self.scrollBoth, idx=i) to the scrollbar and passing idx to scrollBoth, but then I get an error saying "scrollBoth() got multiple values for argument 'idx'"

Comment: I updated the code above with what I have been trying recently.

Answer (score 2):

As the same set of widgets will be repeatedly created, it would be better to embed them in a class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class BalanceLog(tk.Frame):
    months = [
        ['January', 31],
        ['February', 28],  # Check for leap year
        ['March', 31],
        ['April', 30],
        ['May', 31],
        ['June', 30],
        ['July', 31],
        ['August', 31],
        ['September', 30],
        ['October', 31],
        ['November', 30],
        ['December', 31]
    ]
    def __init__(self, parent, month):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tk.Label(self, text=self.months[month-1][0], font='CourierNew 12 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        tk.Label(self, text='Day', bd=1, relief='raised').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        tk.Label(self, text='Ending Balance', bd=1, relief='raised', anchor='e').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')

        sb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.on_scroll)
        sb.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='ns')

        self.day_list = tk.Listbox(self, width=3, activestyle='none', exportselection=0, yscrollcommand=sb.set)
        self.day_list.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.day_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_select)

        self.balance_list = tk.Listbox(self, width=16, activestyle='none', exportselection=0, justify='right', yscrollcommand=sb.set)
        self.balance_list.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')
        self.balance_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_select)

        # fill the listboxes
        for day in range(1, self.months[month-1][1]+1):
            self.day_list.insert('end', day)
            self.balance_list.insert('end', str(day)+',999,999.99')

    def on_scroll(self, *args):
        self.day_list.yview(*args)
        self.balance_list.yview(*args)

    def on_select(self, event):
        selected = event.widget.curselection()[0]
        # update selection of another listbox
        another = self.balance_list if event.widget is self.day_list else self.day_list
        another.selection_clear(0, 'end')
        another.selection_set(selected)
        another.see(selected)
```

Then create the required items using the class:

```
root = tk.Tk()
for month in range(1, 13):
    BalanceLog(root, month).pack(side='left')
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just trying to understand Tkitner in general as the documentation is pretty light when it comes to doing anything beyond simple widgets. I updated my code above using lists, but I can't get both listboxes to scroll.

Comment: Did you use my code as it works fine in my Python environment.

Comment: Not yet as I don't fully understand embedding, and don't want to code something I don't understand. I wanted to attempt this both ways, one with your embedding method, and my code I updated above using lists.